# Combining GMSMutablePaths

Tags: ios, google-maps, concatenation, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have

```
GMSMutablePath *pathLeft;

GMSMutablePath *pathRight;
```

I want to combine the two into one GMSMutablePath. I can't seem to find a method in Google Maps iOS to concatenate the two.

I tried creating the new GMSMutablePath by 
    GMSMutablePath *newPath = pathLeft;

and then using the normal combine array method:

```
[newPath addObjectsFromArray:pathRight];
```

This does not work. According to the documentation "GMSMutablePath is a dynamic (resizable) array of CLLocationCoordinate2D."

Do I just need to loop and add each CLLocationCoordinate2D from the second to the first array? Or is there a method out there already for this?